# Can play .ts files in Samsung android phones

Tags: android, video, stream, video-streaming

I'm trying to play .ts files from server.It is playing without any problem in Pipo tablet but not Samsung devices.Using following code(using a VideoView) I tried to play .ts files

```
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    String vidAddress="http://.../test/BF4_MP_LAUNCH_TRAILER_60FPS_ESRB-145117-10042015.ts";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    vidView.start();
```

i think this a problem in Samsung device.How can I fix this problem?.Is there a way to attach other player(that can play any devices) to my application or are there any other class or interface that can use with app.Please need quick help.

Comment: Please point out where on [the list of supported media formats in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) your desired format is. I am not aware that Android supports MPEG2, and I do not see it in that list.

Comment: @CommonsWare, `.ts` is a container-format (=transport stream), and could wrap various encodings, even though it's generally used to wrap MPEG-TS as specified in MPEG-2. The page you linked lists it as a Network protocol, as well as in the Audio and Video sections. Provided the video stream in question contains AAC audio, it should play.

Comment: @323go: Many thanks, and my apologies to the OP for missing that.